# Understanding the Joomla Component File Structure / from URL

Tags: joomla

I'm new to joomla and have got a problem with a website.

I need to modify a view and I've been told it is in

`http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=register&Itemid=68`

It has a registration form and i need to modify its field. I've access to FTP only. I need to know where are these files to modify the registration form. If one can describe the meaning of this url structure then it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the template files in /components/com_user/views/register/tmpl.

However, you should create an html/com_user folder in your template directory with a copy of those files and use a template override ("never" edit core files).

Here are a couple resources that will point you in the right direction:
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Thank you. That's what I need to know about. @user1855126

Answer (score 1):

com_user means use the user component register view.
Itemid 68 refers to the id of the menu item it is linked from.

You don't want to directly modify any joomla files.

If you want to add a field to registration activate the user plugin or create your own user plugin along the same design but with the fields you want.

Comment: Thanks for the description @elin

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable not to modify the core files directly, they will get overridden whenever the Joomla is updated.

However what you are looking for is available at components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml file. you can change the default fields of the registration form in this file.

If you would like to add additional fields to registration form, there is a better way:
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin